# Positioning of the Table Notes of a threeparttable

Tags: horizontal-alignment, threeparttable

How to position (center) the 'tablenotes' of a threeparttable? Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have done all the necessary code, but i need few help in the formatting process. The table is to be included to an Elsevier single column manuscript. It's look weird in the current formatting. Please help.

For making the task clear, i am writing the code. The table consisting * marks shown as superscript inside the table and defined using the table notes. Please find the code.

```
\documentclass[preprint,3p,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}

\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Identified search terms for the above defined Research Questions.}
\label{t0}

\begin{threeparttable}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\scalebox{0.9}
{
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\hline
RQ.~\# & Identified Terms\\\ 
\hline

RQ.~1  & SOA\textsuperscript{*}, cost estimation\textsuperscript{*}, effort estimation\textsuperscript{*} \\\
RQ.~2  & approach\textsuperscript{*}, technique\textsuperscript{*}, SOA cost, SOA scope \\\
RQ.~3  & classification\textsuperscript{*}, ranking, type \\\ 
RQ.~4  & validation, evaluation, empirical study\textsuperscript{*} \\\
RQ.~5  & future work\textsuperscript{*}, improvement \\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item [*] Note: These search terms are having synonyms or alternate spellings or abbreviations.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If that is all there is to the table, just remove the `\scalebox`.

Comment: What do you mean by "How to position (center) the 'tablenotes' ". You mean to center them?

Comment: Yes Sir.. I mean the same # Harish Kumar

Comment: @TorbjørnT. It works. But if i want the same to fit in two column.. What will be the procedure for that?

Comment: @SibaMishra fit what into two columns?

Comment: @daleif. Of course the above mentioned table. Because \begin{table*} didn't work for the same.

Comment: Could you turn your code snippet into a complete example, starting with `\documentclass`, ending with `\end{document}`?

Comment: Sure. It's edited and mentioned, in the code snippet area. Star mark (*) didn't work, as it was expected. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Sorry if I'm being difficult here, but weren't you talking about a two column Elsevier article? Your code is one column, standard `article`.

Comment: Yes Sir. you are right. The above mentioned code is for one column article. But, sir, my question is: if i need to format the same table for a two column Elsevier article, what other things i need to take care off? I am asking this because \begin{table*}  \end{table*} - [*] is not working in this case. Hope this helps. Waiting for your reply sir. Thanks in advance. @TorbjørnT.

Comment: Are you using Elsevier's documentclass (`elsearticle`)? If so, please edit your code example to reflect that. That said, what do you mean by `table*` not working? I would guess it does what it is intended to do, i.e. spread the table over both columns. If you don't want that, use `table` instead of `table*`, as usual.

Comment: Sir, @TorbjørnT. I have changed it, according to the Elsevier template. But still the table* is not working. You can check this sir.

Comment: The error I get from that has nothing to with the class, but with the fact that you have three backslashes at the end of each row, where it should be two.

Comment: Three backslashes isn't a issue sir, i have check that reducing it two back slash. Moreover, Using table* didn't spread the table over both the columns. It is strange and i am facing the same scenario. Sir, how to expand the size of the above mentioned threeparttable. Sir, you have suggested don't use \scalebox. But if i want to expand the size of the table, such that it fits entirely over the width of the paper (width of the page, not height). How to do that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Too long for a comment, will delete if this doesn't solve the problem.)

In the below code you'll find two versions of the table, one where it fits into a single column, one where it's wider. The table doesn't extend to the width of the page. But then, if you're submitting this to Elsevier they'll likely re-typeset everything anyway.

The `lipsum` package and `\lipsum` commands is only there to create dummy text, don't include them in your own document.

[image]

```
\documentclass[preprint,twocolumn,3p]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{threeparttable,array,booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1] %dummy text
\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Identified search terms for the above defined Research Questions.}
\label{t0}    
\begin{threeparttable}    
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}    
\begin{tabular}{l >{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{0.75\columnwidth}}
\toprule
RQ.~\# & Identified Terms\\ 
\midrule
RQ.~1  & SOA\textsuperscript{*}, cost estimation\textsuperscript{*}, effort estimation\textsuperscript{*} \\
RQ.~2  & approach\textsuperscript{*}, technique\textsuperscript{*}, SOA cost, SOA scope \\
RQ.~3  & classification\textsuperscript{*}, ranking, type \\ 
RQ.~4  & validation, evaluation, empirical study\textsuperscript{*} \\
RQ.~5  & future work\textsuperscript{*}, improvement \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [*] Note: These search terms are having synonyms or alternate spellings or abbreviations.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table*}
\centering
\caption{Identified search terms for the above defined Research Questions.}
\label{t1}

\begin{threeparttable}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}

\begin{tabular}{l l}
\toprule
RQ.~\# & Identified Terms\\ 
\midrule
RQ.~1  & SOA\textsuperscript{*}, cost estimation\textsuperscript{*}, effort estimation\textsuperscript{*} \\
RQ.~2  & approach\textsuperscript{*}, technique\textsuperscript{*}, SOA cost, SOA scope \\
RQ.~3  & classification\textsuperscript{*}, ranking, type \\ 
RQ.~4  & validation, evaluation, empirical study\textsuperscript{*} \\
RQ.~5  & future work\textsuperscript{*}, improvement \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\begin{tablenotes}
\item [*] Note: These search terms are having synonyms or alternate spellings or abbreviations.
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}

\end{table*}
\lipsum\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: thnks a lot sir.. @Torbjorn

Comment: No problem. Just stop calling me 'sir'.